# Socket reference in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to nodejs and was experimenting with socket.io. I am trying to send message to specific sockets so I thought I will store references to the socket.

```
var controls = {};
var clients = {};

var control = io
  .of("/control")
  .on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("connect_player", function(data){
      var id = data.screen_id;
      controls[socket.id] = id;
    });

    socket.on("msg", function(data){
      id = controls[socket.id]
      player.socket(clients[id]).emit("msg", data);
    });
  });

var player = io
  .of("/player")
  .on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("set_id", function(id){
      clients[id] = socket.id
    });
  });
```

I first start a webpage which connects to the "player" namespace and displays an id(hard coded). Then another webpage which connects to the "control" namespace with the same id as player, now the controller should be able to send messages to that particular player but this works for a while and then fails.

During the period when it works I can send messages from the control page to the specific player page.

I looked at the sockets ids in the player namespace after it stopped working and found the socket ids are different from the initial ones.

I guess I am doing something wrong here or has a wrong understanding of the concepts. How can I fix this problem.

**Edits:**

I added listeners for "reconnect" event and found that the value of socket.id changes after each the "reconnect" event. So the controls and clients have invalid socket.id values which casues my problem. Is there away to overcome this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Newest socket.io supports rooms. So how about this? For each connection set a unique ID for this connection (for example the unique username - this works great together with session - or whatever you want). Then you can use

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   // retrieve the ID from socket
   socket.join('/priv/'+ID);
});
```

Then you can do the following in `msg` handler:

```
// get the ID
io.sockets.in('/priv/'+ID).emit("msg", data);
```

At this point you can be sure that the message went to the user you want. Of course you need make sure that the ID won't change when the client reconnects. Like I mentioned before - this can be done by sending session cookie to the server and retrieving the ID from session.

And I think this is the only acceptable solution, because the client may reconnect many times and you would want other clients to recogonize this particular client by for example (unique) name.

Comment: I have edited my question. The problem I am facing is due to the fact that I am using socket.id as reference which seems to change after reconnect.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I advice not using it. For each client define and set your own ID and use rooms to maintain private messaging.

Comment: In my experience, you should use RedisStore to use "Room" feature. Because Socket.io uses Redis's subscribe, unsubscribe feature to implement "Room"

Comment: I tired it @freakish and it is not working too..it behaves like my original code...I tied changing the settings like anand suggested and it seems to be working..but I dont know whether its the right way to do it.

Comment: @josnidhin What do you mean it's not working? It has to work! You must be doing something wrong. :) When the client connects he has to send his name to the server. The server stores the name and runs `sock.join('/priv/'+name);` on this particular connection. It has to work, there is no way it won't. :)

Comment: freakish is right. You should expect disconnects and reconnects, and the socket.id changes between them. Use cookies to maintain the session, or have the client send a UUID upon his connection event, and base your metadata upon this UUID and not socket.id

Comment: I am doing some experimental stuff during my free time so didnt use any frameworks so my current code is a bit messy. I tried this method in a simple hello world and it seems to be working. Now just have to figure out why it didnt work in my actual code.

Comment: @freakish Your answer doesn't make sense because on a subsequent msg handler, the only reference you have is the socket and its corresponding ID. So the subsequent 'get the ID' you have will reference a different room.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try setting the heartbeat interval as

```
 io.set('heartbeat interval', 20); 
 io.set('heartbeat timeout', 60);
```

Comment: I dont think this would help me. I tried it and nothing changed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Which version of socket.io are you using?

Comment: Presume it would be v 0.9.1. This version changed heartbeat timeout and interval defaults (60 and 25 seconds) on the server side and implemented client side heartbeat checks.

Sorry. I missed out another setting in the earlier comment. It should read

io.set('heartbeat interval', 20);
io.set('heartbeat timeout', 60);


The client-side timeout is the same as the server side polling interval by default (here 25 seconds). It takes time for messages to cross the internet (even localhost), a typical lag of about 5 seconds. So this setting should resolve the issue.

Comment: @almypal What does that have to do with OPs issue? Setting a heartbeat will keep socket ids consistent? Your answer also could just be a comment as it really doesn't help explain anything. Also, in trying this I get "io.set is not a function"