# Node.JS Socket.IO sending packets to specific connection IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have been searching for this particular problem for the past week, and since I couldn't find any information on the subject(that wasnt outdated), I just decided to work on other things.  But now I am at the point where I need to be able to send data(that I constructed) to specific clients using their ID who are connected to my server using node.js and socket.io.  I already store the ID in an object for each new connection.  What I need to know is a way to just send it to a connection ID I choose.

Something like:  function send(data, client.id) {};

I am using an http server, not TCP.

Is this possible?

edit:

```
server = http_socket.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(respcont);
    client_ip_address = req.header('x-forwarded-for');
    });
socket = io.listen(1337);   // listen
//=============================================
//  Socket event loop
//=============================================
socket.on ('connection', function (client_connect) {
    var client_info = new client_connection_info();     // this just holds information 
    client_info.addNode(client_connect.id, client_connect.remoteAddress, 1); // 1 = trying to connet

    var a = client_info.getNode(client_connect.id,null,null).socket_id; // an object holding the information.  this function just gets the socket_id
    client_connect.socket(a).emit('message', 'hi');

    client_connect.on('message', function (data) {
         });
    client_connect.on ('disconnect', function () {

    );
});
```

solution:  I figured it out by just experimenting...  What you have todo is make sure you store the SOCKET, not the socket.id (like i was doing) and use that instead.

```
client_info.addNode(client_connect.id, client_connect.remoteAddress, client_connect, 1)

var a = client_info.getNode(client_connect.id,null,null,null).socket;
    a.emit('message', 'hi');
```

Comment: Just for your information, HTTP is a protocol that works over TCP connections.  And TCP is a protocol that uses IP, which in turn uses (mostly) ethernet, which uses electrical or optical signals.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I just didn't want to get help for a TCP version rather than an http version (if that makes a difference).  Actually, I just learned about that not to long ago!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this, the easiest thing to do is to build and maintain a global associative array that maps ids to connections: you can then look up the appropriate connection whenever you need and just use the regular send functions. You'll need some logic to remove connections from the array, but that shouldn't be too painful.

Comment: I know there has to be some way to accomplish what I want to-do, because it was possible in later versions of node.js and socket.io.  edit: I already store the connection ids, what else do I need to store along with them?

Comment: I accepted your answer as it was right.  I just couldn't understand what you were trying to convey.

Comment: @Femi Good solution if you are not thinking about scalability. It would be really difficult to make it work on multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
io.sockets.socket(id).emit('message', 'data');
```

Comment: Hm, I cant seem to get it working.  Ill update my code with how I call things.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has one major drawback: scaling. What will you do when your app needs more the one machine? Using internal IDs also could be difficult. I advice using external IDs (like usernames).

Similarly to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662141/socket-reference-in-socket-io/9663664#9663664) I advice using rooms (together with Redis to allow scaling). Add private room for every new socket (basing on user's name for example). The code may look like this:

```
socket.join('priv/' + name);
io.sockets.in('priv/' + name).emit('message', { msg: 'hello world!' });
```

This solution allows multiple machines to emit events to any user. Also it is quite simple and elegant in my opinion.

Comment: I cant use a solution like that for a server game engine.  I must create objects for every player with their socket and database information.

Comment: Of course you can. To store data associated to given socket you can use `socket.set` and `socket.get` together with JSON encoding. You should reverse the concept: hold the info inside socket (good), not socket inside info (bad).