# How do you reference a Socket.IO socket elsewhere in Node.js / Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm new to Socket.IO and doing some experimenting to better understand.

I'm trying to figure out how I can reference a socket/session/namespace elsewhere in the code besides the io.on section.

Googling has not proven successful

> close but not quite
> [Socket reference in Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662141/socket-reference-in-socket-io)

I'm expecting it to be something very simple [can't see the forest for the trees]

Thank you!

Here is my sample code where I'm getting a reference error:
testsocket.js

```
http.listen(3000,() => {
    console.log('Listening on *:3000');
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.emit('displayMsg', 'Server Connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

var timerobj = {IdCount:1};
let timerId = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`tick ${timerobj.IdCount}`);
    
//  \/ Reference error here  
    socket.emit('displayMsg',`Count ${timerobj.IdCount}`); //broadcast to all
    timerobj.IdCount++;
    if (timerobj.IdCount > 10){
        clearInterval(timerId);
        console.log('timeId exit');
    };
}, 2000);
```

testsocket.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Testing Socket.io</h1>
    <span id=messageArea>Intial page load message</span>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const $messageArea = document.getElementById('messageArea');
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('displayMsg', (msg) => {
          $messageArea.innerHTML = msg;
          console.log('Message received and set');
        });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this specific example, you would change ```socket.emit``` to ```io.emit``` which will broadcast to all connected sockets. The ```socket``` you are trying to reference is out of scope and would only reference one single socket rather than all of them.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Is there a way to reference a single socket outside of the io.on() statement?

Comment: It depends on what you’re trying to do. Generally you want to add all of your socket logic inside of the io.on(“connected”). Then you can attach events to the sockets to listen for messages from the sockets and reply to that socket. However if for some reason you need to access the specific socket outside of its scope, I would assume you could store a reference to that socket outside of that scope. I don’t use socket.io too often so I’m not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Thank you for the added explanation. That got me pointed in the right direction. I appreciate your time!